# No error without VStack. Is there a case where I don't need to write VStack?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I tried the following and got no error.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("A")
    Text("B")
  }
}
```

I think all the examples in the net for vertical alignment use `VStack`.

I feel like I would have gotten an error if I didn't use `VStack`.
Is this writing style OK?

If I don't use `alignment` or `spacing` of `VStack`, can I use this style?

Xcode: Version 12.4, Simulator: iOS14.4

Comment: It is ok, since SwiftUI 2.0 `body` has `ViewBuilder` by default, so you have it like in `Group { ... }` container.

Comment: What would the benefit be? You save typing a few characters but your code will be less clear.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I simply did not get the error, so I asked the question.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson If "OK" seems confusing, would it make more sense if it was "Safe"?（I'm not very good at English, but I'm trying pretty hard to write it.）

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Oh. I see.

Comment: Here is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68869423/weird-toolbar-with-nested-conditionals-behavior) that gives an example of what can happen in this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Asperi commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68860939/no-error-without-vstack-is-there-a-case-where-i-dont-need-to-write-vstack#comment121697603_68860939), it's ok to omit the `VStack`. But there *is* a "catch": When using previews, each view will get its own device. As far as I know this is the only thing that's different.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("A")
        Text("B")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: 2 phones, first shows A, second shows B]

Answer (score 0):

It is not neccessary to use VStack in View builder. You need it when you specifically want to align the views vertically otherwise the View Builder has a default alignment.

Answer (score 0):

When you are returning a custom `View`, SwiftUI would return `VStack { CustomView() }` by default under cover, because it has implication of `@ViewBuilder`, your `CustomView()` allowed to have maximum of 10 renderable `some View` or `View` in it's `body` and also minimum of 1. Also you can explicitly change it before you return it in a cusom code.

But when you are returning `some View`, SwiftUI expect just one single renderable view type, it could be a `VStack`, `HStack`, `Circle`, `Text` or etc.

So backing to your question you are trying to return a `View` not `some View`, then there is no need for VStack, except that you want some custom spacing or alignment.