# Weird toolbar with nested conditionals behavior

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm getting this extremely odd issue where if you have a deep chain of `ViewBuilder`'s and if statements, along with a toolbar, some of the items in the toolbar duplicate.

Here is an image to show what I mean (Notice the 2 "Press me!" buttons)

[image: screenshot)]

**Reproduction: (Note: I'm using macOS Monterey Beta 5 and Xcode 13 Beta 5)**

1. Create a new blank SwiftUI macOS project
2. Paste this code into `ContentView`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Sidebar")
            SecondPanel()
        }
    }
}
struct SecondPanel: View {
    @State var num = 0
    
    @ViewBuilder var content: some View {
        Text("Line 2")
        Text("Line 3")
    }
    @ViewBuilder var contentWithToolbar: some View {
        content
            .toolbar {
                Button(action: {
                    num += 1
                }) {
                    Text("Press me!")
                }
            }
    }
    var body: some View {
        if num == 0 {
            contentWithToolbar
                .navigationSubtitle("Num is zero!")
        }
        else {
            contentWithToolbar
        }
    }
}
```

3. Run the app. You should see two "Press me!" buttons even though I only have one toolbar button!

I was wondering, what is going here, and is there any way I can solve this problem?

Comment: Try removing the view builder annotation from the button. I would generally use that if I’m performing conditional logic when creating that view. Since you’re not it should be okay without the annotation

Comment: @Jake I tried removing it, but it doesn't seem to help

Comment: Okay… how about wrapping the content view builder contents in A vstack?

Comment: @Jake That seemed to solve the issue, but originally I had a bunch of conditionals (hence the ViewBuilder)

Comment: Awesome! Glad it helped

Comment: @Jake Oh shoot, I totally forgot about that

Comment: Please don't edit your question to announce that it's solved. That's what answers are for. And you've posted your answer already (which is great!). I rolled back your edit, accordingly.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Oh, ok. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Jake pointed out that the problem was caused by the 2 Text objects being stacked without a `VStack`.

Adding a `VStack` fixed the problem completely.